# R convert variables to new columns

Tags: r

Maybe this is a stupid question but I cannot think clearly to do it. I want to convert variables in rows to columns and select only 1 variable that I am interested in. Please see from picture 1 to 2

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvZ4Z.png)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qlCM.png)

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert a single factor column to multiple boolean columns, you could try:

```
new_tbl <- tbl_df(model.matrix(~factor(col_name)-1,data=df))
# rename the columns of your new table with something like: colnames(new_tbl) <- c("A", "B", "C")

df <- left_join(df, new_tbl, by = "id") # where "id" is a key found in both tables.
```

Then you can drop columns you don't want by name

```
df <- df[,!(names(df) %in% c("B", "C"))]
```